# SugarCRM 7 - How to share code between views

Tags: javascript, php, backbone.js, sugarcrm

I am adding logic to a custom module in its RecordView. 
Now I want to be able to use the same code in my CreateActionsView.

How can one achieve this in an upgrade-safe approach in SugarCRM 7.2.x without having to copy and paste the same logic to the other view?

I should be able to do this by injecting my code to the stock `record.js` and then calling my functions from my inherited views but this would not be upgrade-safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can package your common JS code as a separate script library and have it included into the page via the JSGroupings extension.  If you extend one of the existing JSGroupings (such as sidecar.min.js) then that will ensure that your JavaScript is pulled into the page.

http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.5/50_Extension_Framework/Extensions/JSGroupings/

By using an Extension, your addition of the JS code would be upgrade safe.